# Prerender Styling in Svelte (Kit)

Tags: svelte

I use svelte-kit but when i reload the page it first shows without styling until the page is loaded. How can I pretender the scss on the server?

I have a __layout.svelte where I import my base scss

```
import '../style/style.scss';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
<style lang="scss" global>
    @import '../style/style.scss';
</style>
```

If you do this, it will add those styles globally and it works amazing!